# Issue with am onclick javascript button on a Visualforce page

Tags: visualforce, javascript, custom-button, button

I'm having an issue getting a button to execute javascript correctly on a Visualforce page. The button is supposed to execute an Apsona Merge Action, but instead, it just refreshes the page.

When I put the javascript into a Custom Button, it works fine. So I know the javascript itself is working, but there must be something wrong with the way I have it here:

```
<apex:includeScript value="https://service.apsona.com/sfdc/apsona_inline.min.js"/>
<script type="text/javascript">
    // script to make sure Apsona has session ID
    sforce.connection.sessionId = "{!$Api.Session_ID}";

    // hack that prevents Salesforce from always putting focus
    // on the first date field
    window.onload = function() { }
</script>

<button onclick="apsona.runAction ('buttonMerge', { 
'actionId': 'a2Of0000000RJ1BEAW', 
'recordId': '{!Campaign.Id}', 
'linkFieldId': 'Id', 
'element': this 
 });">VIP CRCF</button>
```

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I blieve if you add `return false;` it will stop refreshing the page.. and to keep the code clear you can move the method into Javascript function and call it from the onclick Handler

```
<apex:includeScript value="https://service.apsona.com/sfdc/apsona_inline.min.js"/>
<script type="text/javascript">
    // script to make sure Apsona has session ID
    sforce.connection.sessionId = "{!$Api.Session_ID}";

    // hack that prevents Salesforce from always putting focus
    // on the first date field
    window.onload = function() { }

    function callApsona(){
        apsona.runAction ('buttonMerge', { 
                'actionId': 'a2Of0000000RJ1BEAW', 
                'recordId': '{!Campaign.Id}', 
                'linkFieldId': 'Id', 
                'element': this 
        });
    }
</script>

<button onclick="callApsona();return false;">VIP CRCF</button>
```